# Tinymce editor adds random <p> and<a> tags

Tags: tinymce

I'm facing a problem on tinymce editor. whenever I add some anchor tags, save and close it and again open the editor it shows unwanted and random anchor tags as well as paragraph tags. Need some solution to this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce needs a [root block element](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3Aforced_root_block), which is a paragraph by default, in order to be able to style content. So removing those paragraphs will only result in all content being wrapped into one single paragraph because tinymce is forced to use this as root block element.

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see here, the problem is the whenever i open the editor the below gets added

<p><a name="Test1"></a>Test1</p>
<p><a name="Test1"></a><a name="Test1"></a></p>
<p><a name="Test1"></a><a name="Test1"></a><a name="Test2"></a>Test2</p>

ideally it has only one anchor tag for Test1 and another anchor tag for Test2.